# RandomForestClassifier categorial / numerical variables

Tags: python-2.7

I try to understand how `RandomForestClassifier` works.
I read in the documentation that it can accept continues and categorical features.
I also read that in python we cannot give strings values.

So, i convert my string features (categorical variable) into numerical features using `LabelEncoder`

Now my question is: how python know if a variable should be treat as a continuous variable or as a categorial one?

For exemple, if I want to predict if I have a friut or a vegetable.
My feature vector was:

```
food= ["apple","eggplant","orange","courgette","banana",....]
```

those 3 fruits and 2 vegetables appears lot of time in the feature vector

I use `LabelEncoder` and get:

```
food=[0,1,2,3,4,5,.....]
```

If python know that it is a categorical variable it will try to break the tree using:

```
if new_food in [0,2,4]: 
    fruits 
else: 
    vegetable #(and we will have good results)
```

If python think it is a continuous variable it will try to break the tree using:

```
if new_food<3: 
    fruits 
else: 
    vegetable #(and we will have bad results)...
```

If I want to predict if I buy food for kids or for adults (lets imagine that kids prefers fruit than vegetable) regarding the food and the quantity of food.
I will give python 2 vector of features:

```
food=[0,1,2,3,4,5,.....]
quantity=[5,3,2,4,5,1.....]
```

How can I tell python that food is a list of int that should be consider as categorical values but quantity is a list of int that should be consider as a continuous variable????

I hope my question is clear enough....

I cannot find anything on that subject. I suppose python read any variable as categorical ones but this would lost one of the avantage of the random forest (be able to mixe type of variables....)

Comment: Hi, for those who are interested by this question, I have my answer. There is no catagorical variables il numpy. Every variable are consider as continuous variables.